# How to pass a dictionary as value to a function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, mincemeat

In python, I am using the mincemeat map-reduce framework

From my map function I would like to `yield (k,v)` in a loop, which would send the output to the reduce function (sample data given which is the output of my map function )

```
auth3 {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'physics': 1} 
auth34 {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}
....
```

There would be many such entries; this is just a few as an example.

Here, `auth3` and `auth34` are keys and the respective values are dictionary items

Inside the reduce function when I try to print the key,values, I am getting "too many values to unpack" error. My reduce function looks like this

```
def reducefn(k, v):     
    for k,val in (k,v):
        print k, v
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your dictionary with python built-in `dict`

```
>>> dic1 = dict(auth3 = {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'physics': 1}, 
        auth34 = {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1} )
>>> dic1
{'auth3': {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'physics': 1}, 
        'auth34': {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}}
```

Then, your reduce function may go as

```
def reducefn(dictofdicts):     
    for key, value in dictofdicts.iteritems() :
        print key, value
```

In the end,

```
>>> reducefn(dic1)
auth3 {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'physics': 1}
auth34 {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def reducefn(*dicts): #collects multiple arguments and stores in dicts
    for dic in dicts: #go over each dictionary passed in
        for k,v in dic.items(): #go over key,value pairs in the dic
            print(k,v) 

reducefn({'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'physics': 1} ,{'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1})
```

Produces

```
>>> 
physics 1
practical 1
volume 1
chemistry 1
practical 1
volume 1
```

Now, regarding your implementation:

```
def reducefn(k, v):
```

The function signature above takes two arguments. The arguments passed to the function are accessed via `k` and `v` respectively. So an invocation of `reducefn({"key1":"value"},{"key2":"value"})` results in `k` being assigned `{"key1":"value"}` and `v` being assigned `{"key2":"vlaue"}`.

When you try to invoke it like so: `reducefn(dic1,dic2,dic3,...)` you are passing in more than  the allowed number of parameters as defined by the declaration/signature of `reducefn`.

`for k,val in (k,v):`

Now, assuming you passed in two dictionaries to `reducefn`, both `k` and `v` would be dictionaries. The for loop above would be equivalent to:

```
>>> a = {"Name":"A"}
>>> b = {"Name":"B"}
>>> for (d1,d2) in (a,b):
    print(d1,d2)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

This occurs because you're essentially doing this when the for loop is invoked:

```
d1,d2=a
```

You can see we get this error when we try that in a REPL

```
>>> d1,d2=a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    d1,d2=a
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

We *could* do this:

```
>>> for (d1,d2) in [(a,b)]:
    print(d1,d2)


{'Name': 'A'} {'Name': 'B'}
```

Which assigns the **tuple** `(a,b)` to `d1,d2`. This is called unpacking and would look like this:

`d1,d2 = (a,b)`

However, in our for loop `for k,val in (k,v):` it wouldn't make sense as we would end up with `k`,and `val` representing the same thing as `k`,`v` did originally. Instead we need to go over the key,value pairs in the dictionaries. But seeing as we need to cope with n dictionaries, we need to rethink the function definition.

Hence:

```
def reducefn(*dicts):
```

When you invoke the function like this:

```
reducefn({'physics': 1},{'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1},{'chemistry': 1})
```

`*dicts` collects the arguments, in such a way that `dicts` ends up as:

```
({'physics': 1}, {'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}, {'chemistry': 1})
```

As you can see, the three dictionaries passed into the function were collected into a tuple. Now we iterate over the tuple:

```
for dic in dicts:
```

So now, on each iteration, dic is one of the dictionaries we passed in, so now we go ahead and print out the key,value pairs inside it:

```
for k,v in dic.items(): 
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use zip

```
def reducefn(k, v):
    for k,val in zip(k,v):
        print k, v


>>> reducefn({'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'physics': 1} ,{'practical': 1, 'volume': 1,     'chemistry': 1})

practical {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}
volume {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}
physics {'practical': 1, 'volume': 1, 'chemistry': 1}
>>>
```

`reducefn(k,v)` : constitutes a tuple of tuples `((k1,k2,k3..), (v1,v2,v3...))`

zippping them gives you `((k1,v1), (k2,v2), (k3,v3)...)` and thats what you want